# Am I using the Cursor correctly? It wont stop running

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to use the following code to import values into a table, when I tried to compile it, it ran all night and did not stop. I was told to use a cursor because of the amount of data that is being processed in for this. Is there a problem with how my cursor is being used? When I tried to run this with out the cursor I get the following error:

> ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows

```
DECLARE
    lv_count NUMBER;
    lv_cat NUMBER;
    CURSOR c_rate IS
    SELECT INSTR(a.review, b.seed_words), b.categoryid
    INTO lv_count, lv_cat
    FROM review a, SeedWords b
    WHERE a.IDhotel = 1;    
BEGIN
    FOR rec_rate IN c_rate
    LOOP
        UPDATE RATINGS 
        SET RATING = lv_count;

        COMMIT;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

My tables are as follows:
Ratings table (trying to fill in the "rating" column):

```
HOTELID | CATEGORYID | RATING
   1    |        1   |    5
   1    |        2   |    10
   1    |        3   |    2
   1    |        4   |    6
   2    |        1   |    6
   2    |        2   |    10 
   2    |        3   |    4
   2    |        4   |    2
```

Review Table:

```
REVIEW ID | Hotel Id | Review 
   1      |   1      |  "LARGE STRING"
   2      |   1      |  "LARGE STRING"
   3      |   1      |  "LARGE STRING"
   4      |   1      |  "LARGE STRING"
   5      |   1      |  "LARGE STRING"
   6      |   1      |  "LARGE STRING"
   7      |   2      |  "LARGE STRING"
   8      |   2      |  "LARGE STRING"
   9      |   2      |  "LARGE STRING"
  10      |   2      |  "LARGE STRING"
```

Seed word table:

```
SEED ID| SEED_WORD|CATEGORYID
  1    |  "WORD"  |      1
  2    |  "WORD"  |      1
  3    |  "WORD"  |      2
  4    |  "WORD"  |      2
  5    |  "WORD"  |      3
  6    |  "WORD"  |      3
  7    |  "WORD"  |      4
  8    |  "WORD"  |      4
```

I also have a Category table that is very small and is as follows:

```
CategoryID | Category_NAME
1          |      PRICE
2          |      SERVICE
3          |      CLEANLINESS 
4          |      LOCATION
```

Comment: Your update statement do not have where condition so it will update all records of the table ratings... how to map your cursor with rating table is also important. Also, join condition between the tables in cursor query us missing. Is it intetional? It will do cross join.

Comment: The seed word table contains cretin words I'm looking for in the review table. I don't know of a way to join them. Seed word table contains a seedID Seed_words and Category ID review table has ReviewID, Hotel ID, Review date, and Review. I think there has to be a common column in order to join 2 tables. right?

Comment: Once you define the relationship between the tables I am 100% sure you will not need a cursor. If there is no linking column, then on what basis are you updating the ratings table? Has to be some relationship.

Comment: I am updating the rating table based on the amount of seed words found in the reviews for each category.

Comment: Show us the definition of all the tables that are used in the query and also mapping tables if any

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to `SELECT INTO` anymore with cursor. `SELECT INTO` is expecting the result to be single row and set the value of the variable to the returned result.

By using curser, you can refer the field value by `c_rate.fieldname`

Also, do you realize you are updating the RATINGS table for every iteration? Do you mean this?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I did not realize i was doing that. I need to update the RATINGS table after it finds the INSTR value for the category ID there are 4 category IDs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to

1. Not use a `SELECT...INTO`. That's a singleton SELECT, not a cursor.
2. Add a WHERE clause to your UPDATE statement so you only update the single row you want to.

So your code block should look something like

```
BEGIN
  FOR rec_rate IN (SELECT INSTR(a.review, b.seed_words) AS NCOUNT,
                          b.categoryid
                     FROM review a, SeedWords b
                     WHERE a.IDhotel = 1)
  LOOP
    UPDATE RATINGS 
      SET RATING = rec_rate.NCOUNT
      WHERE RATINGS.something = rec_rate.something_else;  -- I have no idea how your tables relate - fix this
    COMMIT;
  END LOOP;  -- rec_rate
END;
```

Unfortunately I don't know anything about your data, so I don't know what field you could be retrieving in your `rec_rate` cursor which would relate to something in your RATINGS table - you'll have to fix this. But that's the general idea.

Comment: I'd remove COMMIT from the loop.

Comment: I agree with @Littlefoot. Also are you sure that this is a correct code block since the cursor ends at IS? That is clearly an unfinished line.

Comment: You're correct - I got distracted mid-edit. Thanks. I left the COMMIT in the loop as per OP's code.